# Does creating a dump .DMP file of main 'chrome.exe' using task manager save any cookies, .png etc.?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, cookies, dump, incognito-mode

I had an incognito window still runing, but completely unresponsive.

I created a memory dump file of main 'chrome.exe' in the Windows 7 task manager. Is there a chance that it saved sesion cookies from an lost project on the site? And can you extract them without being a google engineer with skils in binary coding.